# Do I report 1098-T's box 2 (Amount billed for tuition) amount if I have not paid to it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, education, tuition

I am very confused on this one. In regards to Education Credit Expenses, do I enter box 2 (Amounts billed for qualified tuition and related expense) of form 1098-T if I have not paid on the billed amount? I have searched around the web quite a bit and I can not get an answer. Without entering the amount I owe $2k and with it entered I get back $400. That is a big difference so I want to make sure I enter it right.

Answer (score 1):

Box 2 is not usually all that useful.  It's Box 1 that you will generally use.  The usual question is whether to reduce the amount in Box 1 by the stuff in Box 5 or not.  The answer to this question will depend on your situation.